# Graphite: Match digit suffix

Tags: graphite

***THIS IS SPECIFIC TO GRAPHITE***

I have the following series:

- `Foo`
- `Bar1`
- `Bar2`
- `Baz1`
- `Baz2`

I'd like to only match series with a digit suffix. But when I use `*[0-9]`, only Bar1 and Baz1 are matched.

Comment: Your actual question is not about regex, it is about Graphite *wildcards* that may be used to define the seriesList.

Comment: I've removed the regex tag.